# Pandas columns headers split

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with colums header made up of 3 tags which are split by '__'

E.g

```
   A__2__66    B__4__45
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I know I cant split the header and just use the first tag with this code; `df.columns=df.columns.str.split('__').str[0]`

giving:

```
   A    B
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there a way I can use a combination of the tags, for example 1 and 3.

giving

```
   A__66    B__45
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I've trided the below but its not working

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('__').str[0]+'__'+df.columns.str.split('__').str[2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with `f-string`s for select first and third values of lists:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('__').map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}__{x[2]}')
print (df)
   A__66  B__45
0    NaN    NaN
1    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN
3    NaN    NaN
4    NaN    NaN
5    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: @Erfan - yop, if need last value of lists then it is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

With specific regex substitution:

```
In [124]: df.columns.str.replace(r'__[^_]+__', '__')                                                                          
Out[124]: Index(['A__66', 'B__45'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try split and join:

```
df.columns=['__'.join((i[0],i[-1])) for i in df.columns.str.split('__')]
#Columns: [A__66, B__45]
```

Answer (score 2):

I found your own solution perfectly fine, and probably most readable. Just needs a little adjustment

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('__').str[0] + '__' + df.columns.str.split('__').str[-1]
```

```
Index(['A__66', 'B__45'], dtype='object')
```

---

Or for the sake of efficiency, we do not want to call `str.split` twice:

```
lst_split = df.columns.str.split('__')
df.columns = lst_split.str[0] + '__' + lst_split.str[-1]
```

```
Index(['A__66', 'B__45'], dtype='object')
```